# How to copy data from one JList to Another JList

Tags: java, jlist

So, I have a two tabs, both of which have JList's and they both have an arraylist in which their data is stored, now I need to find a way that will enable be to copy data from one JList in one tab to another JList in another tab.

Thansk

Comment: Mind if you add some code?

Comment: Cant will get all my marks taken away by the snakes who betray there classmates and Nottingham University. Especially Kyle. If you could just let me know a way of doing it or if there are any java functions which can help me simplyfy the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you have and intend exactly, this works, but then they would share the ListModel, not copy:

```
list2.setModel(list1.getModel());
```

Else loop through the elements from one model and add into to the other.

```
ListModel model = list1.getModel();
DefaultListModel list2Model = new DefaultListModel();
for (int i=0; i<model.getSize(); i++) {
  list2Model.addElement(model.elementAt(i);
}

list2.setModel(list2Model);
```

Comment: I like the sound of looping through the elements as copying the entire list model would not be ideal as I would like to retain the previous data within the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you have to set the Models for each jList

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
DefaultListModel listModel2 = new DefaultListModel();
```

I think that you have stored the data into the first jList, so you just pass it into the second jList as follows:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {                                         
   int index=LV.getSelectedIndex();
   listModel2.addElement(LV.getSelectedValue());
   LV2.setModel(listModel2);
   listModel.remove(index);
}
```